# How to validate "Hangul-Korean" text?

Tags: java, regex, internationalization

I want to validate a "Hangul-Korean" text in java.

I will be having the "Korean" text in the "String" and calling "matches()" i will be validating the string.

The regular expression is to test whether that text is "Korean" and that Korean string characters length is in some range like 10 to 20.

I don't want to use any other third party solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: boolean result = Pattern.matches("\\p{IsHangul}{10,20}", "김인재");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference a Unicode block or a script for that.

Here's an example with a script:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsHangul}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("김인재");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: 김
Found: 인
Found: 재
```

**Notes**

- For a reference on Unicode blocks, see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm).
- For a reference on Korean machine characters see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers).
- To validate a range of numbers of characters, use: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsHangul}{min,max}");` where `min` is your minimum size and `max` is your maximum size of Hangul characters.
- The code you posted as a comment to your question will not work (although it will compile). Please find a reference on how to use Java `Pattern`s / `Matcher`s [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

---

**Caveat** for legacy Android versions (9 or lower)

- It seems this methodoogy will not work with Android < 10 and may even crash the runtime.
- Will not test or add an alternative here
- The specific rationale may be buried somewhere [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern#behavior-starting-from-api-level-10-android-2.3) or in linked pages
- Credits to [NoHarmDan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4588511/noharmdan) for the heads up

Comment: Thank You Mena, I believe that this should work and i tried this before coming to "stack overflow", but it is not working. i will give you the sample cod.

Comment: @user3515080 You're welcome. Please post the sample code in your question. Will take a look. **Edit** your code implies some misunderstandings on how Java `Pattern`s and `Matcher`s work. I've posted a working example for you in my answer.

Comment: Thank You Mena. Actually i am new to this validation with "Pattern" and "Matcher", the way of my writing the code itself was wrong. Anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi Mena, how are you ? I have another question, how to allow only numbers with range for "Hangul" ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3515080 Hi, you should post a new question in that case. Good luck!

Comment: Heads-up for anybody needing this on Android: this will crash on Android 9 and lower. I haven't found a working alternative yet.

Comment: @NoHarmDan cannot verify this at this time but it sounds a little crazy that a simple Java pattern with a script crashes a whole Android application. Are you sure it's not something else?

Comment: @Mena 100% sure. I have several testing devices and it is confirmed that Android 9 does not have the same regex capabilities as 10 and newer.

Comment: @NoHarmDan that is quite the find. Did you manage to dig out any official-looking documentation illustrating this capability gap? Maybe some ICU lib differences?

Comment: @Mena the documentation does mention a change in the backend in Android 10, however I haven't had the time (or need, to be frank) to read it very thoroughly and didn't see anything related to this particular issue. See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern#unicode-support

Comment: @NoHarmDan thanks, forgot to mention I was gravitating around that as well (hence the mention to ICU as a possible related element) but hard to tell 100% indeed within this specific context...